# @SpyBean not working with MapStruct mapper

Tags: spring-boot-test

Is there any way to @SpyBean a class that generated by MapStruct

```
@Mapper
public interface EMapper {

    Foo(Boo boo);
}
```

if i try to test

```
class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    @SpyBean
    EMapper mapper;
```

i got the error

Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is `org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.EMapper]: Specified class is an interface`

Comment: yes it works, but i do not want to add specific implementation  , coz if i change implementation of this interface  test was failed

Comment: Why are mokito cant find the current implementation by himself

Comment: what?how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

finally found solution:

```
1.Change @WebMvcTest to @SpringBootTest + @AutoConfigureMockMvc

2.Remove @MockBeans and @SpyBeans from beans, that i do not to override
```

this way init context and get needed beans from it even if they are some interface implementation

if you need to override some behavior of bean method use `@MockBean` or @`SpyBean`

Comment: If you do it like this, spring will bootstrap the whole application for one single test. This might lower your test execution speed. You can test it without the whole context by using the concrete implementation EMapperImpl class, which is generated by Mapstruct, instead of the Interface itself.

Answer (score 0):

Spring tries to construct the instance for the mapper field, but because in a `@WebMvcTest` it does not have a full application context, it cannot find the implementation by itself. It should be sufficient to point spring to the right implementing class, like:

```
@SpyBean(EMapperImpl.class)
EMapper mapper;
```